# Regexp to add and remove text before file ending

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to change the src of an image.

```
var string = "/images/myimage.png";
```

on mouseover I want to add _hover to myimage ("/images/myimage_hover.png")
and on mouseout I want to remove "_hover".

Does anyone have a good Regexp for this?

Thanks

Comment: +1 just for the nick "meow" :P - for more cats in teh interwebz (and more cheezburgers too, of course)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One idea:

```
$('#imageid').hover(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', function(i, val) {
        return val.replace(/^(.+)(\..+)$/, '$1_hover$2');
    });
},
function() {
    $(this).attr('src', function(i, val) {
        // assuming image names don't contain other `_hover` text
        return val.replace('_hover', ''); 
    });
});
```

*Update:* Also check the expressions of the other answers, some are more sophisticated ;) But using `attr` with a callback is a good approach.

Comment: Thanks for remembering that it's "src" for `<img>` tags and not "href" :-)

Comment: +1 For using attr() with a function argument instead of calling attr() twice to read+write.

Comment: That regex could be simpler as just `replace( /(\.[^.]+)$/, '_hover$1' );`

Comment: Great! Thanks! I used your solution with ThiefMaster's Regexp

Comment: Btw, what does "i" do? function (i, val)

Comment: @meow: See the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/attr/ It is the index position of the element in the set. It is not important in your case, but if you have something like `$('div').attr('something', function(i, val){...});` and you have a lot of divs, then `i` would be the index of the div in the set `$('div')`. Not sure if it is really necessary, but it shows consistency. A callback for `.each()` also takes as first argument the index and as second the element itself: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 4):

*edit* oops - it's "src" for `<img>` tags, not "href"

Well you can get the URL itself with:

```
 var imgUrl = $('#imageId').attr('src');
```

Once you've got that, you can *add* the "_hover" with:

```
 imgUrl = imgUrl.replace(/^(.*)\.png$/, "$1_hover.png");
```

and *remove* it with:

```
 imgUrl = imgUrl.replace(/_hover\.png/, '.png');
```

Thus to set things up for proper hovering:

```
 $('#imageId').hover(
   function() {
     var $img = $(this);
     if (!/_hover\.png$/.test($img.attr('src')))
       $img.attr('src', $img.attr('src').replace(/^(.*)\.png$/, '$1_hover.png');
   },
   function() {
     var $img = $(this);
     $img.attr('src', $img.attr('src').replace(/_hover\.png$/, '.png');
   }
 );
```

I included a test in the first function to try and prevent "foo_hover_hover.png" from happening.

Comment: You want to add $ to match only at the end of the string.

Comment: +1 for the `_hover` test. Might not be necessary, but one should be aware of the possibility.

Comment: @Felix King - well I figure it's pretty risky to bet that browsers will always be 100% perfect about tracking mouse moves :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution which works no matter what your file extension is:

```
yourString = yourString.replace(/^(.+)\.([^.]+)$/, '$1_hover.$2'); // do this onmouseover
yourString = yourString.replace(/^(.+)_hover\.([^.]+)$/, '$1.$2'); // do this onmouseout
```

Demo:

```
js> var yourString = 'meow.test.png';
js> yourString = yourString.replace(/\.([^.]+)$/, '_hover.$1');
meow.test_hover.png
js> yourString = yourString.replace(/_hover\.([^.]+)$/, '.$1');
meow.test.png
js>
```

Comment: Thanks! I used Felix Kling's solution together with your Regexp. Works great!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var testString = '"/images/myimage.png';
var regExp = /(.*)(\.)(.*)/g;
var testHover =  testString.replace(regExp, "$1_hover$2$3")
alert(testHover); //Hover Image
alert(testString.replace("_hover", ""));//Regular Image
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered not storing the extension with the filename? If your formats are consistent or if you store the extension separately you can make your life easier. That way, if your naming scheme changes, the chances of your regex breaking are lower.

```
i.e.
var str = "/images/myimage" + (is_selected ? "_hover" : "") + ".png"
```